# regex to validate dateformat from url and otherwise

Tags: regex

I need a regex, that validates this 2 patterns:

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
```

and

```
yyyy-MM-dd%20HH:mm:ss
```

the second one is for `Get` parameters of a url.. thats why there is a `%20` in there.

Edit:

I tired this one:

```
^\d{4}\/([0]\d|[1][0-2])\/([0-2]\d|[3][0-1])(\s([0]\d|[1][0-2])(:[0-5]\d){1,2})*\s*([aApP][mM]{0,2})?$
```

but it does not work

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: @diegod see in the Edit: section of my question :)

Comment: the regex you shared is using `\/` instead of `-` in the date section. It would work otherwise. The `%20` just requires you to unescape the string before using the regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}(?:%20| )[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}
```

This'll work if you're in JavaScript.

You can also place the separate parts in capture groups and check them if you need to validate e.g. that month is less than 12